# Computer becomes unreachable on lan after some time

Tags: wireless, networking, connection, routing, ping

I work on my laptop and ssh into my desktop. I use a lot of key based authentication for many servers for work but recently I couldn't login because ssh would pick up and try all the keys and it stops trying before ultimately falling back to password based login. So right now I am using this command: `ssh -X -o PubkeyAuthentication=no ashfame@192.168.1.4 #deskto`

The issue is after sometime the desktop would just become unreachable from laptop. I won't be able to open its localhost through IP and today I tried ping'in it and found a weird thing. Instead of `192.168.1.4`, it tries to ping `192.168.1.3` which I am sure is the root cause as it just can't reach `192.168.1.4` when its actually trying for `192.168.1.3`

Ping command output:

```
ashfame@ashfame-xps:~$ ping 192.168.1.4
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.4 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 9047ms
pipe 3
```

Also the ping command message comes in multiple and not one by one.
(izx answer's the weirdness I thought there was in ping command.)

I did check for desktop, its local IP is still the same, so something is going on in my laptop. Any ideas?

P.S. - `Laptop` runs Ubuntu `12.04` & `Desktop` runs Ubuntu `11.10`

Laptop is connected through wifi to router and Desktop is connected through LAN to router.

Update: Even after setting up static IP leases in router settings, I again ran into this issue.

Comment: Your wifi may be broken...

Comment: @izx broken as in? It used to work fine before. I have been doing this for months, I guess an upgrade messed it up. Also having another issue related to audio hardware on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

```
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

`ping` is **not** somehow mysteriously reaching `.3` in its quest for `.4` -- you must go through `.3` to get to `.4`, and this is `.3` telling you it can't reach `.4` to complete the connection.

This message usually comes from a gateway or even your localhost. The latter is more likely since gateways are usually `.1`s. What is your laptop's IP? Does it otherwise have internet connectivity? If so, this may be a problem with your router rather than with the computers.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. It was `.3` I just assigned static IP lease on LAN to see if that helps.